# After changing the graphics driver, it doesn’t detect the second HDMI display and I can’t change the brightness

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, hdmi, brightness

After changing the graphics driver, it doesn't detect the second HDMI display and I can't change the brightness.

Hello.
My OS is **Ubuntu 20.04**. My graphics card is GTX 1660ti mobile and laptop HP OMEN.
I needed to change the graphics driver from open source X.org X server to Nvidia 470 for better performance, occasional system crashes and the texturing unit in the gazebo program was not working properly.

After changing the graphics driver, my second monitor and brightness settings stopped working.
After changing back from 470 to open source, everything works as before.
Also, `nvidia-settings` doesn't work. "ERROR: NVIDIA driver is not loaded"

I tried to change to another graphics driver like 515, 510 but nothing helped.
I also turned off secure boot, tried `ubuntu- autoinstall`, `prime-select`, lightdm, update kernel and many other things I found on the internet, but nothing helped.

Therefore, I would like to ask you for advice, for which I would be very grateful.

Thank you for every answer.

xrandr:

```
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 1920 x 1080, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 1920 x 1080
default connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   1920x1080     77.00*
```

[Nvidia-bug-report](https://we.tl/t-WJM6Wc3IzG)

lshw -c video:

```
  *-display UNCLAIMED       
   description: VGA compatible controller
   product: TU116M [GeForce GTX 1660 Ti Mobile]
   vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
   version: a1
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:bb000000-bbffffff memory:90000000-9fffffff memory:a0000000-a1ffffff ioport:4000(size=128) memory:c0000-dffff
```

dmesg |grep -i nvidia:

```
[    1.134452] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[    3.987994] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=3 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input14
[    3.988061] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=7 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input15
[    3.988105] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=8 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input16
[    3.988144] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=9 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input17
[    3.988182] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=10 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input18
[    3.988222] input: HDA NVidia HDMI/DP,pcm=11 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:01.0/0000:01:00.1/sound/card1/input19
[    4.510072] nvidia-gpu 0000:01:00.3: i2c timeout error e0000000
[   12.926918] audit: type=1400 audit(1662012991.674:7): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe" pid=3139 comm="apparmor_parser"
[   12.926922] audit: type=1400 audit(1662012991.674:8): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="nvidia_modprobe//kmod" pid=3139 comm="apparmor_parser"
```